# ¿nombre, cantidad, precio y el total de un array?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

NO USAR CLASES Y OBJETOS

**El array no me deja almacenar palabras** como lo soluciono

Crear un programa que permita al usuario capturar N números de productos, su respectiva cantidad y su precio unitario.

De la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el usuario digita tres productos mostrar:
como puedo hacer para que mi array guarde los nombre del producto y muestre los resultados como la imagen  o en lista

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    int nombre;
    int p; // precio
    int a; // cantidad
    int suma = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Cuantos productos compro");
    a=entrada.nextInt();
    
    char [] array1 = new char [nombre]; //nombre del producto
    int [] array2= new int [a];//cantidad de productos
    int [] array3= new int {p]; // precio
    
    int total1[] = new int[a];
    int total2[] = new int[a];
    
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        System.out.println((i+1)+"Nombre del producto: ");
        array1[i] =entrada.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println((i+1)+"Cantidad de producto: ");
        array2[i]=entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println((i+1)+"Precio de producto: ");
        array3[i]=entrada.nextInt();   
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) { 
      resultado1[i] = array2[i] * array3[i]; // multiplicar el precio x cantidad
      suma += resultado1[i]; // sumar el resultado de (precio x cantidad
     }
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){ // mostrar producto
      System.out.print(nombre[i] + " \n ");
     }
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){ // mostrar cantidad
      System.out.print(a[i] + " \n ");
     }
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){ // mostrar precio
      System.out.print(p[i] + " \n ");
     }

      for(int i=0; i<resultado1.length; i++){ // mostrar resultado total1
      System.out.print(resultado1[i] + " \n ");
     }
      System.out.println("\n");
     }
      System.out.print("Total es: "+ suma);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los tags que usaste no nos dicen en que lenguaje esta esto. Aparte de eso, cual es el problema particular que tuviste?

Comment: Ya probaste eliminando `charAt(0)`  de  `array1[i] =entrada.next().charAt(0)`  y cambiando el tipo de dato de `arrray1` a `String[]`?